# Haskell monadic parser with anamorphisms

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, recursion-schemes, anamorphism

My problem is how to combine the recursive, F-algebra-style recursive type definitions,  with monadic/applicative-style parsers, in way that would scale to a realistic programming language.

I have just started with the `Expr` definition below:

```
data ExprF a = Plus a a |
              Val Integer deriving (Functor,Show)
data Rec f = In (f (Rec f)) 
type Expr = Rec ExprF
```

and I am trying to combine it with a parser which uses anamorphisms:

```
ana :: Functor f => (a -> f a) -> a -> Rec f
ana psi x = In $ fmap (ana psi) (psi x)

parser = ana psi
          where psi :: String -> ExprF String
                psi = ???
```

as far as I could understand, in my example, `psi` should either parse just an integer, or it should decide that the string is a `<expr> + <expr>` and then (by recursively calling `fmap (ana psi)`), it should parse the left-hand side and the right-hand side expressions.

However, (monadic/applicative) parsers don't work like that:

- they first attempt parsing the left-hand expression,
- the `+`,
- and the right-hand expression

One solution that I see, is to change the type definition for `Plus a a` to `Plus Integer a`, such that it reflects the parsing process, however this doesn't seem like the best avenue.

Any suggestions (or reading directions) would be welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a monadic parser, you need a monad in your unfold:

```
anaM :: (Traversable f, Monad m) => (a -> m (f a)) -> a -> m (Rec f)
anaM psiM x = In <$> (psiM x >>= traverse (anaM psiM))
```

Then you can write something that parses just one level of an `ExprF` like this:

```
parseNum :: Parser Integer
parseNum = -- ...

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = -- ...

parseExprF :: Maybe Integer -> Parser (ExprF (Maybe Integer))
parseExprF (Just n) = pure (Val n)
parseExprF Nothing = do
    n <- parseNum
    empty
        <|> (Plus (Just n) Nothing <$ char '+')
        <|> (pure (Val n))
```

Given that, you now have your recursive `Expr` parser:

```
parseExpr :: Parser Expr
parseExpr = anaM parseExprF Nothing
```

You will need to have instances of `Foldable` and `Traversable` for `ExprF`, of course, but the compiler can write these for you and they are not themselves recursive.

Comment: Thank you so much! After a lot of staring at types, it now makes sense! I was wondering, how would you implement anaM if the parser was an Applicative instead of a Monad? I am (desperately) trying to work my way into that.

Comment: @Matei Not possible. But look into selective applicative functors. I haven't worked out the details but suspect they should be powerful enough to write `anaM`.